# How to disable HyperV in Windows 2012 Datacenter

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, azure

I'm needing to install VMWare inside of an Azure instance running Win2k12 Datacenter edition.

Under Control Panel -> Server Manager -> Remove Roles, it tells me Hyper-V is not installed, so I'm not able to remove it there.

Under msconfig, I have about 6 or so hyperv entries, but disabling them and restarting still does not allow VMWare to install, which complains that HyperV is running.

Comment: @Ramhound Hyper-V is installed as a Role, not an application.

Comment: Cannot be removed as a Role either, see screenshot: [cannot remove HyperV](http://i.imgur.com/2sYZIWk.png)

Comment: Is your Azure instance running as a VM on HyperV? Running virtual machines instead of virtual machines does not end well.

Comment: I'm not sure of how Microsoft has setup Azure. Is it completely not possibly to run VMWare under this infrastructure or just not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run any OS virtualization software, such as VMWare, on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine. You may run a Linux or Windows Server OS image as a vm, but it will run under the Windows Azure virtualization infrastructure.